# Is there a way to obtain the variable importance for a specific class in Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, image-classification, random-forest

I used a .smileRandomForest() and I know that by calling .explain() you can see the relative importance of the variables for the general classification... but I would like to know which inputs contributed the most for a specific class within my classification scheme. Is there a way to conduct this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try a one versus rest classifier approach. Turn your multi-class into a two class being non-target and target. And then look at the importance metrics for that model. You can repeat the process N times, where N is the number of original classes you have...this will give you relative importance for each class.